# Write a Mix task that runs after deps.get

Tags: build, elixir, elixir-mix

Is there a way to hook into Elixir's Mix built in tasks to execute a task after another one has completed?

I know you can do something similar to this.

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Other.Get
  use Mix.Task

  @shortdoc "Other dependencies?"
  def run(_) do
    Mix.Task.run("deps.get")
  end
end
```

But I kindof want a task to run right after `mix deps.get` considering using `make` to wrap the commands that make the most sense. (ie `make deps` which would run both `mix deps.get` then `mix other.get`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [Mix alias](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.html#module-aliases) for that:

```
defmodule MyApp.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :my_app,
      version: "1.0.0",
      aliases: aliases()
    ]
  end

  defp aliases do
    [
      "deps.get": ["deps.get", "custom.task"]
    ]
  end
end
```